# important considerations when expected monthly returns seem implausible relative to the purchase price of real estate?

Tags: real-estate

as a concrete example: this property has been on the market for two months for $39,000 with tenants who allegedly pay $1,000/month in rent.  before taxes, that's a 31% annual return.  could anyone detail why a property like this isn't scooped up right away?

https://www.redfin.com/MD/Baltimore/1517-E-Lanvale-St-21213/home/10783631

[image]

Comment: You are ignoring taxes and maintenance that may not be that cheap in the end potentially.

Comment: taxes are negligible, aren't they?  from the link: `Finances & Fees Tax Year: 2014 Total Taxes: $354`  maybe maintenance?  so there's just a hole in the roof or something not disclosed in the listing?

Comment: That would be my thought as the house is 115 years old that would make me wonder what renovations have been done to keep the insides up to date along with what possible crimes may have happened near there.

Comment: Did you see the school ratings? Isn't it a big hint?

Comment: @littleadv nope.  the question isn't: why the price is so low?  the question is: why is the ratio of purchase price to monthly return so low.

Comment: downvoters please clarify what could be improved about this question thanks

Comment: Because the monthly rent is not $1000. They may have a signed lease for that amount, but I'm pretty sure that's not what they're able to actually collect.

Comment: I downvoted because the question is speculative and is off topic. Unless you expect someone to actually go out there and research the neighborhood, all you're going to get is guesses.

Comment: @littleadv so then you think the listing agent is lying or being deceitful?  `currently brings in $1,000.00/month` is a quote. thx

Comment: currently. they don't know what will it bring next month. You can ask to see their bank statements to verify, but I don't think they'll show you. All you will get is the lease.

Comment: @littleadv i have gone out in the neighborhood and visited houses.  it doesn't make sense.  that's why i'm asking here.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico - Welcome to Money.SE - I'm sorry to say, this is not the forum for this type of question. You can go to the help section, take the tour, etc, and see what is asked and answered here. What you want is [Bigger Pockets](http://www.biggerpockets.com/) a forum that deals exclusively with real estate investing. Enough members that when you spell out the question, a few from that area are likely to give you a great answer. I hope to see you post the question there.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer hi, the sentence `The financial aspects of homebuying` from https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic could distinguish residences from investments more explicitly?

Comment: @AnthonyDamico - Yes. I have two choices. I can explain how and why your question is (a) opinion based, or (b) too specific, not likely to help a future visitor, and help you edit to something generic enough that it would would stand, i.e. remove the listing, offer just the vague details, etc. (Which Philipp's answer would still address) Or give you the referral to a great site that's perfect for you. Investment real estate questions are fine, yours is just too specific, "analyze this deal", not a question we can address.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer sorry for appearing too specific, i'd been wondering about this question for a while and only posted this property after i already had the question in mind and sought out a suitable example.  i've edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

Where you able to take a closer look at the property? Address and size in m² aren't everything which determines the price of real estate. Just some facts which greatly affect the value of real estate could be:

- Problems with the building itself: It might have structural issues, be infested with vermin or mold, require intensive remodeling because of new building regulations, problems with the plumbing and many more reasons which require a huge investment to make it livable again. The building is over 100 years old. The older the building, the more likely it is to have some big problem which lowers the value.
- Speaking of age: Some older buildings can be protected heritage sites even when in private ownership. This means the owner must keep the property in good and historically accurate condition. This can be very expensive, because it often requires the services of specialized companies.
- Problems with the environment: Maybe there is some planned project nearby which will soon drastically lower the value of the property, like a highway, railway or factory built nearby.
- Problems with the tenants: Sometimes you have problematic tenants who generate more cost than they are worth, but you can't get rid of them easily due to a tenant-friendly rent contract or due to local laws which protect them from eviction.
- You might buy the building, but is the land it stands on part of the deal? It might be a [leasehold estate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leasehold_estate) deal where you own the building but still pay rent for the ground.

When a real estate deal seems too good to be true, then there usually is a reason. Remember that the market is full of professional real estate traders who are constantly on the lookout for cheap real estate to buy so they can resell it for a higher price. When this real estate would really be underpriced, they would already be fighting for it. But apparently they don't. Likely because their professional expertise tells them that this deal is far worse than it looks.

Comment: Nice list of issues. Curious about the land lease - wouldn't the seller/agent need to disclose this in the listing?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I am not a lawyer, but I am quite sure they would, but they might try to hide it in the fineprint and/or try to downplay the issue.

Comment: I'll just leave this here.   http://www.biggerpockets.com/renewsblog/2015/03/03/why-you-cant-make-money-on-30000-houses/

Comment: Ha. Yes, @Knuckle-Dragger - that was one of the articles I had in mind.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer it will be in the title, but in this case since the lot size is explicitly mentioned, I don't think its a land lease. But its a crappy neighborhood with low-income population that cannot maintain $1K rent a month. Buying it is becoming a slamlord, and most investors don't want the headache.